# Are there more Combination methods?

Tags: combinatorics

Ia there another method possibly? A group consists of 8 boys and 4 girls. Find the number of  different ways that a group of 7 can be chosen if a particular boy is included.

I am getting 1071 ways from isolating this boy and combining others.

eg 3 boys and 3 girls and so on...

Answer (score 2):

There are $11$ remaining children from which $6$ have to be chosen, if we set aside the one special boy. The sex of the remaining children is irrelevant in this case. So I'd say we have ${11 \choose 6} = 462$ options.

Comment: I had this answer earlier but somehow discarded it. I think your argument is correct! gender does not matter now, thanks!